# Asp.net - WHY Page is reloading after Ajax call?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am picking the image from canvas which is in Form. But Button is outside the form. My Images saves exactly as expected but remaining problem is PAGE RELOAD.

Ajax call upon clicking BUTTON to save the image from canvas:

```
$("#upload").click(function () {
    var image = document.getElementById("ModelStudedntImageDP").toDataURL("image/png");
    image = image.replace('data:image/png;base64,', '');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "../../Admin/UploadImage",
        data: '{ "imageData" : "' + image + '" }',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (msg) {
            alert(msg);
        }
    });
});
```

Button calling:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="upload">Test</button>
```

Controller Method for saving image:

```
public void UploadImage(string imageData)
{
    string filePath = Server.MapPath(Url.Content("~/Content/Images/Teacher/"));

    string fileNameWitPath = filePath + DateTime.Now.ToString().Replace("/", "-").Replace(" ", "- ").Replace(":", "") + ".png";
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileNameWitPath, FileMode.Create))
    {
        using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs))
        {
            byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(imageData);
            bw.Write(data);
            bw.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the controller method look like, could you paste that also?

Comment: If your button is in a form, the default behavior is to submit that form, the ajax post is an extra submission. If this is the case, you'd need to `.preventDefault()`.

Comment: @RistoM My question Updated.

Comment: @Jasen the button has of `type="button"` so it does nothing in a form.

Comment: The code you have shown will not cause a page reload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public JsonResult UploadImage(string imageData)
{
    string filePath = Server.MapPath(Url.Content("~/Content/Images/Teacher/"));

    string fileNameWitPath = filePath + DateTime.Now.ToString().Replace("/", "-").Replace(" ", "- ").Replace(":", "") + ".png";
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileNameWitPath, FileMode.Create))
    {
        using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs))
        {
            byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(imageData);
            bw.Write(data);
            bw.Close();
        }
    }
    return Json(new { success = true, message = "Success" });
}
```

Comment: What does this have to do with the question (changing it from `void` to `JsonResult` has nothing to do with the page reloading)